# How to structure tests in django, for functional vs unit vs other?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

It seems that

```
python manage.py test
```

runs all the tests in `myapp/tests.py`

But say i want to break those up into `myapp/functional_tests.py`, `myapp/unittests.py`, `myapp/ajaxtests.py` what is the recommended way to do that? My functional tests wouldn't have any sense of coverage, while my unit tests would definitely want to report coverage, my "ajax" tests are just an example of something in between.

I would like it so i could run one command that would run all tests (for continuous integration), while being able to pick and choose tests while developing.

Answer (score 1):

You can run separate tests with `python manage.py test monkey.test`, which will run all of the tests in the `monkey.test` module. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests) about that. Or use, my favorite test runner [py.test](http://pytest.org/) which will help you separate tests into folders and make it really easy to run!

Now you might want to have some fancy command and not do the above all the time, then you could use a task automator as [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)!

After doing the normal `pip install fabric`, you setup a fabfile.py in your root folder.
Inside of this you define your tasks that you want to run.

A crude version of this would look like this

```
from fabric.api import local

def run_tests(env):
    local('python manage.py test {0}_test.py'.format(env))
```

And run it from the command line like this

```
$ > fab run_tests:integration
```

With this tool, you've also started on the path of getting your tasks automated and you can also start using Fabric to do your deployment for you and also it integrates really well with CI servers.